# Overwriting memory in 1 instance instead of 2

Tags: python, object, data-structures, instance

I tried to create 2 instances for s1 and s2, but the memory get written twice. 
I get:

```
     Out of the World
     Book: Decision Procedure
      =========================================
     Out of the World
     Book: Decision Procedure

instead of
     Out of the World
      =========================================
     Book: Decision Procedure

How is this so?
```

I created a class  as following:

```
     class domain_monitor:
         name = '';
         tasks = [];
```

I started populating the instances  as following:

```
     s1 = domain_monitor();
     s1.name = "s1";
     s1.tasks.append("Out of the World");


     s2 = domain_monitor();
     s2.name = "s2";
     s2.tasks.append("Book: Decision Procedure");
```

I print the output as following:

```
     for v in s1.tasks:   # 
       print v
     print " ========================================= "
     for v in s2.tasks:   # 
       print v
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `class` definition `tasks` is a static property, meaning that it will be shared across instances. You should use define a `__init__` method to initialize object properties. For example:

```
class domain_monitor:
    def __init__(self):
         self.name = ''
         self.tasks = []
```

By the way, class names must be in `CamelCase` according to PEP8, so `DomainMonitor` would be a better choice.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `__init__()` method to `domain_monitor`, otherwise all you instances will share the same `name` and `tasks`.

So far you have

```
s1.tasks is s2.tasks
>>>True
```

After you add:

```
def __init__(self, name, tasks):
    self.name = name
    self.tasks = tasks
```

All instances will have separate properties.